# How can I create this menu with wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: menus, navigation, dropdown

How can I get this menu with `wp_nav_menu()`? This menu is created with Bootstrap.

```
<ul id="menu-main_menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
    <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-8">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li  id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25 dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Our Founders</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Our Vision</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Our Strategy</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">How We Work</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26 dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Our Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Past Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Current Projects</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27">
        <a href="#">News &amp; Events</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can achieve with a `nav walker`. I used [this](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker). I am stepping according to the mentioned.

1. Put `navwalker` (`wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php`) in your `theme root`
2. Call to the `navwalker` in `functions.php` file. `require_once('wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');`
3. Create your menu in Wordpress Backend (`Appearance -> Menus`)
4. In your menu area, according to me in `header.php`

> ```
> wp_nav_menu( array(
>   'menu' => 'main_menu',
>   'depth' => 2,
>   'container' => false,
>   'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-center',
>   'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
> );
> ```

```
`main_menu` is my menu name
```